# Why isn't thenAcceptAsync() always executed after completion of the parent stage?

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, completable-future

I just started to learn using `CompletableFuture`. I am wondering why the below code is behaving bit strange:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int coreCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(coreCount);

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getStringSupplier(),service)
                     .thenAcceptAsync(getStringConsumer(),service);

    System.out.println(" running main thread");

    service.shutdown();
}
```

In the above code, sometimes the `getStringConsumer()` method is not executed. Can any one please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: That's probably because you shutdown service before it invokes. Didyou try add Thread.sleep(10000) before shutdown service?

Comment: @MaximTulupov Will that make a difference? The task should be scheduled by the time `supplyAsync` returns and `ExecutorService.shutdown` doesn't prevent already scheduled tasks from running.

Comment: If you pass as second parameter your executor, in this case threads from executor will be used, otherwise threads from ForkJoinPool

Comment: But in your code executor can be shutdown before acceptAsync called

Comment: @MaximTulupov Ah...yes. Good catch. _At Pulipati Prasadarao:_ Between the time the `supplyAsync` stage finishes and the `thenAcceptAsync` stage starts the `service` can be shutdown, as Maxim stated. If you put the resulting `CompletableFuture` in a variable then call `join()` _after_ calling `service.shudown()` I suspect you'd get a `RejectedExecutionException` the times when `getStringConsumer` isn't called.

Comment: I added `.thenRun(service.shutdown())` after thenAcceptAsync. Now its working fine but if i want to execute more tasks after these chain of futures it will not allow and also i don't want to use `awaitTermination` because i don't know how long task will run. is there any alternate?

Comment: Thanks all of you guys for fast response

Comment: You can wait for the tasks to complete before executing the subsequent tasks. `CompletableFuture` has the `join` method as well as the `get` method inherited from `Future`. They will both block until the future completes (exceptionally or normally). Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @MaximTulupov you should post this as an answer, maybe with some solutions to avoid it.